# Django-simple-history: How do I access the historic values of m2m fields?

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

When accessing the historic data via `historicObj = object.history.as_of([date in the past])` I get the historic values of all fields and all HistoricForeignKey. When accessing many-to-many fields I only get the current data.
`historicObj.m2m_field.all()[0].field = "newData" #not "oldData"`

Do I have to access it like this?

`historicObj.m2m_field.history.as_of([date in the past]`

Thank you in advance.
(I use Python 3.8.10, Django 4.2.0 and django-simple-history 3.4.0 .)